# custom progress dialog using frame animation

Tags: android, progressdialog

I need to use a progress dialog to show a 'please wait' kind of a text and a frame animation in android. is it possible

Comment: Yes.  Lots of things are possible, what is your actual problem you need help with?

Comment: the usual custom progressbar is possible , but can u give a sample code as to how i can get a frame animation to show on the progress dialog

Comment: @manohar3787 if any answer was helpful you should have acpeted

Answer (score 0):

```
ProgressDialog.show(YourActivity.this, "", "Please wait...");
```

to know details about progressdialog go to [this link](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/ProgressDialog.html)

Answer (score 0):

Its extremely simple to set the text and title of a progress dialog, simple use the dialog.setMessage("") and dialog.setTitle("") methods.  As for a custom spinner, it is possible, however it's slightly tricky.  Details of the solution can be found here:

[Custom Android Dialog Animation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5269726/how-to-apply-custom-spinner-image-to-progress-dilalog-in-android)

Comment: i've seen the link but after trying it with frame animation it doesnt work