# Changing default progress wheel inside ProgressDialog with animated gif

Tags: android, android-spinner, progressdialog, animated-gif

I'm trying to set an animated gif as the spinner of a ProgressDialog.
I've tried to follow this post without solving the problem (the spinner simply disappear when it starts the dialog) :

> https://stackoverflow.com/a/25508430/6030866

Please, help me.

Here's my code :

```
@Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(LoansList.this);
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading books. Please wait...");
        pDialog.setIndeterminate(true);
        pDialog.setProgressStyle(ProgressDialog.STYLE_SPINNER);
        pDialog.setCancelable(false);
        Drawable d = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.bookgif);
        pDialog.setIndeterminateDrawable(d);
        pDialog.show();
    }
```

In this way i can only view the single image (not animated).
Please , help me.
I'm using the latest version of Android Studio.

Thank you very much !